# How to allow specific SSL client certificates in Nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

Nginx's `ssl_client_certificate` and `ssl_trusted_certificate` directives can be used to allow client certificates signed by a given authority. But how can I allow specific certificates? I would like to filter by certificate fingerprint, or alternatively, by certificate authority + client cert serial number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nginx has access to the client certificate's fingerprint and serial number in `$ssl_client_fingerprint` and `$ssl_client_serial`, and the issuer's DN with `$ssl_client_i_dn`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables) for details.

You can filter fingerprints by using a `map`.

For example:

```
map $ssl_client_fingerprint $reject {
    default 1;
    87654321abcdef9876543210fedcba123456789a 0;
    fe8765432176543210fedcba12345678abcdef98 0;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($reject) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details, and [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: It has `$ssl_client_i_dn` for the immediate issuer. (In larger PKIs, just using the serial number alone _might not be unique_, but the combination of $ssl_client_i_dn and $ssl_client_serial ought to always be.)